# Unpickling a class raises attribute error

Tags: python, pickle

I wrote a class A in the Class_A.py file

```
class A():
    def square(self, num):
        return num*num
```

Next in pickle_A.py, I saved the class in a file 'class_A_imported_from_class_A'

```
import pickle
from Class_A import A
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = 'class_A_imported_from_class_A'
    with open(file_name,'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(A,f,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Then I moved the file to another location, where I ran Unpickling_imported_class.py to unpickle this file.

```
import pickle

file_name = 'class_A_imported_from_class_A'
with open(file_name,'rb') as f:
    B = pickle.load(f)
```

So, I get the error:

```
  B = pickle.load(f)

builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Class_A'
```

Now, I know that the error will go, if I copied the Class_A into this folder. The constraint is that I cannot.
I was able to do this using cloudpickle, but in that, I have to pickle the file also using cloudpickle.
My work demands that I should be able to unpickle classes directly, i.e. if there's a pickled file that has the data for a class, I should be able to read a class directly. Is there a way that I can do it?

Comment: You can take a look at dill: https://pypi.org/project/dill/

Comment: dill produces the same error

Comment: I made the pickle file with dill in __main__ and I could unpickle it. But dill fails when the class is imported before serializing with dill. Also, the file should be serialized with dill for the unpickling to work.